# Not able to read old Kafka stream using CreateStream

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I am able to read new messages that are getting pushed to the `KafkaStream`, but I am not able to read the old messages.
How can I read all the old messages pushed to the stream when I start with New Topic?

```
kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc,'zookeeper1.sys.net:2181,zookeeper2.sys.net:2181,zookeeper3.sys.net:2181,zookeeper4.sys.net:2181,zookeeper5.sys.net:2181,zookeeper6.sys.net:2181','spark-streaming24',{'TOPIC':3},keyDecoder=lambda x: x,valueDecoder=lambda x: x)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible with receiver, but `createDirectStream` has optional `fromOffsets` argument which takes a dictionary `TopicAndPartition` -> `offset`:

```
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import TopicAndPartition

fromOffsets = {
  TopicAndPartition("topic", i): long(0) for i in range(n_partitions)
}
```

Structured streaming has equivalent `startingOffsets` option

```
df = spark \
  .read \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
  ...
  .start()
```

or with JSON

```
df = spark \
  .read \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("startingOffsets", """{"topic":{"0":0,"1":0}}""")
  ...
  .start()
```